# How to get id when user click on checkbox?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

How to get id when user clicks on checkbox and this check box is dynamically bind/bound. Please help me.

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="test">   
 <table>
 <tr>
<th><input type="checkbox"  id="selectall" class="chk"/></th>
  <td>Account Name</td>
  <td>Billing State</td>
   <td>phone </td>
   <td><input type="button" id="buttonClass" class="button" value="SelectAccount" /></td>
  </tr>

 <tbody data-bind="foreach: accountArray">

 <tr>

<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="text:Id" id="myCheck" name="list"/></td>
  <td><span data-bind="text:Name" /></td>
   <td><span data-bind="text:Billingstate" /></td>
    <td><span data-bind="text:Phone" /></td>

    </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>

 </div>

<script>
$('#buttonClass').click(function() { debugger; 
 var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked; 
  var names = [];
  var i;
  $('#test input:checked').each(function(i) {
     alert(i); 
     names.push(i);
    });
     console.log(names);
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Where do you need the ID? In Javascript or in Apex Controller?

Comment: I need this ,In javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="text:Id" id="myCheck" onclick="jsMethod(this);"  name="list"/>

<script>
    function jsMethod(inputtag) {
        var idProp= $(inputtag).prop('id'); // or attr() 
        var idAttr = $(inputtag).attr('id');
        alert(idProp);
        alert(idAttr);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="text:Id" id="myCheck" name="list" onclick="passtheId(this);"/></td>
```

and then in `passtheId` method using this you will get all details or you can directly pass Id as well.

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: @user29407 what is not working?